# How can I check for the presence of a single flag in tcsh?

Tags: linux, shell, flags, tcsh

I have a bash script that takes the command line flag called "--signal".

When this is specified on the command line, I want to run a line on the command prompt.

Is there a concise way of doing a brief if-statement to check? Getops adds a lot of clutter than I'm not too fond of.

```
if (--signal)
 # Run this line
endif
```

Comment: Do you care about any other arguments on the command line? or just `--signal` ?

Comment: Other command line arguments have code to handle them accordingly. The scope of this post is just for --signal.

Comment: Can't you check for this flag in the same way you check for all the other flags?

Comment: There's no `endif` in `bash`. The end of `if` is `fi`. Your syntax looks more like `csh`.

Comment: My apologies all, it actually may be tcsh rather than bash. I hadn't realized there was a difference.

Comment: @ChristopheBrown so do you want it in `tcsh`?

Answer (score 0):

Brute force but works.  Replace `found`'s value with a boolean and if that is `true` then spin off your process to send signal.

```
#!/bin/bash

found="didn't find it"
for v in "$@"
do
  if [ $v == "--signal" ]
  then
    found="found it"
  fi
done
echo $found
```

Answer (score 0):

The question says "tcsh", but the description says "bash". And then in the comment you mention "tcsh" again. So, I assume you want it in tcsh.

If you don't worry about error checking, like throwing errors for other unsupported arguments etc, this simple if statement does what you want. i.e checks if "--signal" is passed to the script

```
if ("$*" =~ "*--signal*") then
    # Whatever you want to do
endif
```